# What is my java location and how can I point maven to it?

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, maven

I am a UI dev with no experience in Java whatsoever. However, I have a dilema.

```
> / % java --version
openjdk 15.0.1 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and:

```
> / % mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/libexec
Java version: 18.0.1.1, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.1.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_RO, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

The question I have is, why does maven have another version of java, and how can I make it point to the java 15 ?

I also tried this:

```
> / % which java
/usr/bin/java
> / % cd /usr/bin/java
cd: not a directory: /usr/bin/java
```

I thought that the command `which` will point to me to the location where java 15 is stored, however that path does not seem to exist on my computer.

Another thing that I saw is that I do not hava JAVA_HOME set, it is missing.

I am very confused, can somebody help me surpass this issue please?

Edit: Response to the comments:

```
> / % ls -al /usr/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x  52 root  wheel  168432 May 10  2022 /usr/bin/java
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/java` is probably a symbolic link to the `java` executable. Try `ls -al /usr/bin/java`.

Comment: "I thought that the command `which` will point to me to the location where java 15 is stored" no, it points you to the (potentially linked) binary that gets executed when you run `java`.

Comment: what is `$JAVA_HOME` set to?

Comment: @SIMULATAN empty as i said

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I've updated the question with the response for you

Comment: well, try setting it to the right JDK, apparently maven uses the JDK pointed to by this variable

Comment: what is the right path ?  have you read my question ?

Comment: If you have 2 or more JDKs installed and want to switch between them, this might be worth a read if you are using [homebrew switching between multiple JDKs](https://medium.com/@manvendrapsingh/installing-many-jdk-versions-on-macos-dfc177bc8c2b) or use something like https://sdkman.io/

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `JAVA_HOME` variable or as alternative:

```bash
export PATH=<YOUR_JRE_BIN_PATH>:${PATH}
mvn <MAVEN_ARGUMENTS>
```

Comment: I've downloaded a new java 15 and set the path to it but I get : “java” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an issue related to your environment. Nothing to deal with your original question.

Comment: Modern versions of Maven do not need JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

Get JAVA_HOME from the `java` command with

`java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 | grep -E 'java\.home'`

Result

```
 java.home = /usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11
```

Then add an export for JAVA_HOME variable or use it on maven command as

```
JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib64/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11' mvn <something>
```